# How to send laravel's built-in email verification to Gmail users when signing up an account

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, email, gmail

I am trying to send a verification email for gmail users who use their gmail to sign in. The problem I have is that signing up regularly sends a verification email but signing up with gmail does not unless you click send verification email.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Iluminate\Auth\Notifications\MustVerifyEmail;
use App\User;
use Socialite;
use Auth;
use Exception;


class GoogleAuth extends Controller
{
    public function redirectToProvider()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('google')->redirect();
    }

    public function handleProviderCallback()
    {
        try {
            $googleUser = Socialite::driver('google')->user();
            $existUser = User::where('email', $googleUser->email)->first();

            if ($existUser) {
                Auth::loginUsingId($existUser->id);
            } else {
                $user = new User;
                $user->name = $googleUser->name;
                $user->email = $googleUser->email;
                $user->google_id = $googleUser->id;
                $user->password = md5(rand(1, 10000));
                $user->save();
                $user->notify(new Notifications\VerifyEmail);
                Auth::loginUsingId($user->id);
            }
            return redirect()->to('/home');
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return redirect('/register?tryagain');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @rpm192 What do you think by Laravel's `bcrypt()`?

Comment: @rpm192I tried $user->password = bcrypt(request('password')); and it worked for some reason

Comment: Is there a reason to send a verification email to the same third party account used to sign in?

Comment: @adam to verify before using my site for my services

Comment: @SangNguyen, By signing in using a thirdy party service, gmail in this case, is the "email" account not verified?

Comment: @adam you right now that I think about it. How should I do it where it verifies it then?

Comment: Set the `email_verified_at` column. Example: `$user->email_verified_at = \Carbon\Carbon::now()`